# Shortcut for Stepping Down in the VSCode Autocompletion Suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode suggest multiple auto completion options in a list to me. I can navigate the list with the arrow keys, and auto complete using the currently selected item via ENTER. To me, this is counter intuitive, because to navigate with the arrow keys, I have to shift my hand position on the keyboard. I would expect, e.g. TAB to navigate to the next element in the list & hitting ENTER to complete. Is there a shortcut for navigating besides the arrow keys that I am missing?

Comment: There are some potential solutions being discussed here: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/908#issuecomment-366491210

At least when using the vim add-on in VSCode you can use Ctrl+N and Ctrl+P for 'next' and 'previous' suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

alt + '[' or ']' to cycle back and forth.

Comment: don't think particular command works